# Uploading an image with paperclip? Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, paperclip

**Issue:
Nothing is being added to the database table. See code and error below. Can someone explain what I am doing wrong? Thanks!**

---

`User` Model:

```
  has_attached_file :avatar, styles: { thumb: "48x48>" }, default_url: "/assets/:style/missing.png"
  validates_attachment :avatar, content_type: { content_type: ["image/jpeg", "image/gif", "image/png"] }
```

`Dashboard` Controller:

```
  def update
    @user = User.find(current_user)
    @user.update( user_params )
    redirect_to dashboard_path
  end

  def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:avatar)
  end
```

Route:

```
  patch 'profile', to: 'user_dashboard#update'
```

Form/View:

```
<%= form_for @user, url: profile_path, :html => { :multipart => true } do |f| %>
  <%= f.file_field :avatar %>
  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

Error:

```
Started PATCH "/profile" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-08-22 16:31:30 -0400
Processing by UserDashboardController#update as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"TV/CIi/DeO6r8yG5LbqQWWzAl619D7G6QB4fgyoTBRQ=", "user"=>{"avatar"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x0000010b530ed8 @tempfile=#<Tempfile:/var/folders/74/_w090lhj6550xfrvb0rqyyq00000gn/T/RackMultipart20140822-23296-12aqgxz>, @original_filename="apply-icon.png", @content_type="image/png", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"user[avatar]\"; filename=\"apply-icon.png\"\r\nContent-Type: image/png\r\n">}, "commit"=>"Update User"}
  User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users"  WHERE "users"."id" = 1  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
  User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users"  WHERE "users"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
   (0.2ms)  BEGIN
Command :: file -b --mime '/var/folders/74/_w090lhj6550xfrvb0rqyyq00000gn/T/9eb0b264a0bb1300e51e27b15fd7013c20140822-23296-6bphp2.png'
Command :: identify -format '%wx%h,%[exif:orientation]' '/var/folders/74/_w090lhj6550xfrvb0rqyyq00000gn/T/9eb0b264a0bb1300e51e27b15fd7013c20140822-23296-195tr2e.png[0]' 2>/dev/null
sh: line 1: 23444 Trace/BPT trap: 5       identify -format '%wx%h,%[exif:orientation]' '/var/folders/74/_w090lhj6550xfrvb0rqyyq00000gn/T/9eb0b264a0bb1300e51e27b15fd7013c20140822-23296-195tr2e.png[0]' 2> /dev/null
[paperclip] An error was received while processing: #<Paperclip::Errors::NotIdentifiedByImageMagickError: Paperclip::Errors::NotIdentifiedByImageMagickError>
Command :: file -b --mime '/var/folders/74/_w090lhj6550xfrvb0rqyyq00000gn/T/9eb0b264a0bb1300e51e27b15fd7013c20140822-23296-1ywe70.png'
   (0.4ms)  ROLLBACK
```

## Update

Removing the image scaling works:

User Model:

```
  has_attached_file :avatar, default_url: "/assets/:style/missing.png"
  validates_attachment :avatar, content_type: { content_type: ["image/jpeg", "image/gif", "image/png"] }
```

Comment: I believe the `validation` should be `has_attached_file` as well. `validates_attachment_content_type :avatar, content_type: /\Aimage\/.*\Z/`

Comment: Whats the difference? Im explicitly defining content_types... What does  `/\Aimage\/.*\Z/ – ` do?

Comment: Looks like you don't have ImageMagick installed?

Comment: No I did .. I managed to get it working.. See my answer below @Rich thanks though! ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After scratching my head for a while.. I found a solution by doing the following:

```
brew unlink libtool && brew link libtool
 #=>Unlinking /usr/local/Cellar/libtool/2.4.2... 0 symlinks removed
 #=>Linking /usr/local/Cellar/libtool/2.4.2... 17 symlinks created
```

And adding `Paperclip.options[:command_path] = "/usr/local/bin/"` to Application.rb

Lastly updated User#model:

```
  has_attached_file :avatar, styles: {thumb: "100x100"}, default_url: "/assets/:style/missing.png"
  validates_attachment :avatar, :presence => true,
    :content_type => { :content_type => ["image/jpeg", "image/gif", "image/png"] },
    :size => { :in => 0..500.kilobytes }
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a github issue on this error found [here](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip/issues/1405)

The solution should be setting the following in application.rb to the imagemagick installation path.

`Paperclip.options[:command_path] = "/usr/local/bin/"`

Also try wrapping the styles in {}

`has_attached_file :avatar, { styles: { thumb: "48x48>" }}`

Comment: Did you install imagemagick using homebrew? If so your install path for imagemagick is likely /usr/local/bin. This option tells paperclip where the imagemagick is installed in development. Open up the application.rb file or development.rb file and add that line to that file and restart the rails server.